# Laravel multi-tenant approach. Where to start

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, multi-tenant

I've a full application coded. Now, the only part missing is to make it multi-tenancy.

I want to allow clients to register into my application website and get an instance of the application with a completely empty database only for that account.

I've thought to play with environments, but I'm not sure if this is a good approach:

```
config
    - user1
        - database.php
    - user2
        - database.php
    - ...
```

I've also thought about a unique config file containing the database information about every account and set the database connection based on the subdomain name. Something like I've seen in this post:

[Multi-tenant in Laravel4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879803/multi-tenant-in-laravel4)

Any other idea or better approach to do this part?

Answer (score 4):

Your solutions require 1000 folders for 1000 users.
1000 databases, thousand migrations if anything changes during application live cycle.
You don't want this, trust me.

Instead, create one database and use flags/foreign keys to assing data to users, simply said.

Comment: That'd be a bit messy for database maintenance, isn't it? Any recommended reading about this?

Comment: Exactly, maintenance would be hard that way.
I would use `m:n` relations. `M:N` relations results to associative table/entity, which helps you to assign data to another entities (blog posts to author, photos to users, ...) Theory here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_Entities and Laravel implementation here http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Answer (score 3):

As Andreyco points out having 1000 users with 1000 databases will quickly become a joke, but if your user accounts (clients) will be a much smaller number then this is not such an issue.

The best approach is to have one "master database" which contains all of your generic client information, and this is controlled via a "Super Admin" panel which you have access too. This then lists the database configuration details for the other accounts, so store the database information for the other db's in a table in that one.

It's a little less secure, but essentially means that somebody has to hack the main database to get into the other databases, which is unlikely. You should also limit the firewalls of these databases so even if an attacker is in that main db they can't do shit without hacking into one of your web servers and SSHing from there onto the secondary DB's.

Comment: Apart from the security pitfall ,are there any there any other con's of using this architecture ?

Comment: Phil, its been awhile since your comment, have you done any more multi tenant to keep with this approach? And any Posts/Packages/Patterns to look at to implement it?

Comment: I've not done it again since then, but if I did it again that is the approach I would take. You don't need any fancy packages or posts or patterns to do it. :)