# Querying from Remote databases using an ORM ( ie. Eloquent )

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have recently come across a situation where querying from two tables that has about 16k records each.

Executing raw SQL results in the response time to a few seconds and if I opt to stick to the ORM queries, the same results in a nginx request timeout since the query takes more than 1 min to process.

Has anyone faced a similar scenario , I am aware that heavy queries can be made using a Doctrine.

The implementation looks like this. A more detailed explanation on the architecture that is in use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19771835/540771

Laravel App Default Connection connects to DB 1 (has connection details to DB 2). According to the correct connection connects to appropriate DB.

DB 1:

```
connections table ( id, db_name, db_username, db_password, hostname, port)
```

DB 2:

```
customer ( customer_id, name )
customer_details ( customer_id, email, etc ... )
```

The query executes on the DB 2 and looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers as c LEFT JOIN customer_details as cd 
ON c.customer_id=cd.customer_id
ORDER BY c.created_at DESC
```

The row count on the table customers and customer details is 16k each. The relationship is 1 .. * , but the business rules limit it in a way so that there is always 1 customer record maps into 1 customer_details record.

The result that is fetched into a Datatable. Pagination is to be added to limit the number of records returned.

Comment: Would you edit into your question the query itself? I presume it is a `JOIN` of some kind. Is it actually just one query - could you have an N+1 problem? When you say "remote database", do you just mean it is a relational database on a different server, or is it something more complex (e.g. MySQL federated table)? What database are you using?

Comment: @halfer yeah its a simple join query  , no complex expressions. Just two tables joining in and selecting a few fields.  The DB is not federated , but the application consumes 2 databases at once and the second connection is set in run time thats the only difference. MySQL is the database.

Comment: OK, let's see the query please, and an explain plan, **in the question**. What is the second connection relating to? If you run one query, you can only do it through one connection.

Comment: OK, that's better. How many results does the query return? Is it just this query that is slow? Or are you including a fetch from `connections table` in your "slow" assertion?

Comment: the app only connects to the connection table once upon login , and then it continues to connect to the DB2 instance. The issue is , if I execute the SQL above it works fine , less than 300 mil sec to fetch 16k+ records from RDS instance on mysql. But soon as I opt to use the Eloquent Query builder its taking more than 60s to process the request and results in a nginx timeout.

Comment: I would guess that's because it is trying to instantiate 16K objects. You should not need that number in a web app though - either reduce it massively (maybe through pagination) or take your feature to an offline process.

Comment: @halfer yes, I will take a look at the possible options. For now , i have opt to fall back to executing raw a raw SQL and not to use the ORM.

Comment: OK. If you need further assistance, please explain in the question why you need to instantiate 16K model objects. This is very unusual for a web application.