# SAAS - Laravel - Multi tenancy - switch database

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant, saas

I'm going to start a `SAAS` model web application and gone through many searches.

My idea is separate database for each tenant and single code base and each client will have sub domain.

I'm storing tenant details in main database.

Customers will logged in through their sub domain. Now i want to verify `tenant details`(which is stored in main database), then authenticate tenants account and after logged in, i want to show tenant specific data(stored in separate database) from tenant database.

how can I switch database after verify tenant details from main database to tenant database in `laravel 4`? I'm not clear on this. please give your suggestion?

Comment: You dont want to switch databases per user - you want to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16879803/1317935

Answer (score 4):

see this URL

http://www.colorfultyping.com/multi-tenancy-in-laravel-switching-databases-at-runtime/

or using When using multiple connections, you may access them via the DB::connection method:

```
$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);
```